# How to ensafe ActiveDirectory authentication in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, active-directory

I have a Web-Site for some kind of administration. It will only be available within domain network and it must be very safe. That's why I decided to use an existent domain authentication. I have turned Windows authentication and impersonation on. Now, when I open this web-site, the user is already authorized with `WindowsIdentity`.

The first question is how to safely check user's identity within domain group. I mean, I shouldn't let user enter if he is authenticated with non-domain account.
For example, user logs in to Windows with his local machine administrator user, opens my web-site, will `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` be true (*as he is a Windows user, anyway*)? Maybe, I should check for some kind of certificates, sources or owners. How to become sure that our user belongs to our domain and it is not an intruder?

The second question is: I need to determine if a user belongs to a certain groups. I have an ID of a group: `S-1-5-21-1455132813-...`. Is it OK to use this ID for identification of a group? I'm just not sure how static these IDs are. Maybe, there is a more proper way to check it.

Now, I do it this way:

```
private readonly _allowedGroupId; // read from a config

var wi = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
if (wi.IsAuthenticated && wi.Groups.Any(x => x.Value == _allowedGroupId))
{
    // authorized
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For checking Windows roles, you should use role manager:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="WindowsProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="WindowsProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

And check role in code:

```
Roles.IsUserInRole(@"domain\active_directory_role_name")
```

Comment: Yay! That's exactly what I was looking for. Also, I have found a lot of interesting in `System.DirectoryServices` :)